# mongodb ERROR: child process failed, exited with "error number 62"

Tags: mongodb

I spent hours looking around but didn't find much !
I'm trying top migrate an old mongoDB (3.6.20) into the latest and the procedure suggest to proceed gradually, so right now I'm trying to migrate from 3.6.20 to 4.0.20.
Installed new binaries, all ok, however I end up with :

ERROR: child process failed, exited with "error number 62"

Looking here (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/) says :

62
Returned by mongod if the datafiles in --dbpath are incompatible with the version of mongod currently running.

There is some procedure to follow to fix the problem or I have to lose all the data ?
I'm searching but so far I didn't find a clear answer or procedure I can follow to fix this problem.
The problem is that mongo is not even starting. All the suggestion I found so far (like here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/)  imply to be able to access the DB !
So it must exists some external tool or procedure to fix this.

Thanks for any help !
STeve

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue after my brew install of MongoDB was proving to be problematic.
I also experienced an issue with mongosh where I could connect to the db but was unable to run any commands, i could run "show collections" and that was it.  upon running any commands I was constantly receiving error:

```
getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

(for which there were zero posts(let alone anything helpful) on the internet related to mongodb)

I installed from Tar as per the documents.
A suggestion for anybody facing this similar issue is to 
1-brew uninstall mongodb and mongosh
2-then go to usr/local/brew/cask (not sure that's 100% but you can google it to find out) and remove the files related to mongodb and mongosh if they have persisted(mine did).
3- install via Tar as per documentation.
4- brew install mongosh.

Voila, I can now run local community server and do not have any issues running commands in the mongosh shell.

Hope this helps somebody.  Cheers!